# Haskell, recursive data and pattern matching

Tags: haskell

is the first time that I work with the recursive `data`.
I can not solve this problem:

```
data Sseq = S Sseq | E deriving (Show)

testElem = (S, S, E, S)

maxSseq_hlp :: Int -> Int -> [SSeq] -> Int
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax [] = max curmax prevmax
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax ((S x):xs) = maxSSeq_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax xs
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax (E:xs) = maxSSeq_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) xs

maxSseq :: [SSeq] -> Int
maxSseq list = maxSseq_hlp 0 0 list
```

The function maxSseq should return the longest sequence S in a list testElem, using an auxiliary function that remembers the S counted in the previous sequences, but gives me the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Sseq]'
            with actual type `(Sseq -> Sseq,
                               Sseq -> Sseq,
                               Sseq,
                               Sseq -> Sseq)'
In the first argument of `maxSseq', namely `testElem'
In the expression: maxSseq testElem
In an equation for `it': it = maxSseq testElem
```

I do not understand where is the problem, can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok one after the other:

### tuple vs lists

Your `testElem` is not really a list - it is a tuple - so you have to write `[..]` instead of `(..)`

### constructors

Your `Sseq` can either be `E` or `S s` where `s` itself has to be a `Sseq` again - so your `testElem` will not work this way (that's why you got the error saying you used functions `Sseq -> Sseq` (those are the `S`)

I would suggest:

```
testElem :: [Sseq]
testElem = [S E, S (S (S E)), E, S (S E)]
```

this should evaluate (IMO) to either `3` or `S (S (S E))` depending on your desired behavior of `maxSseq` (see below)

Use this and try again (I guess this is Homework of some sort)

#### PS

all the other errors you will see will basically come from misspelling something - mostlikely `SSeq`VS `Sseq` ;)

### more hints:

- Your function will not work (you consume max. one of the `S` while counting)
- You can try to fix this by cleverly reinserting the `x` from `(S x)::xs`
- But I think what you really want to do is first implement a function `len :: Sseq -> Int` and then use this cleverly in some way
- based on your description, what you really want is `maxSseq :: [Sseq] -> Sseq` - so if you stick with your code you have to remember the max. seqence not (only) it's length
- if you are interested you can use my former hint to solve this easily using [comparing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) and [maximumBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy)

I will append my full solution in an hour or so but you should really try it out yourself first.

### solutions (don't read if you are still trying)

ok this is how you can *patch*  your solution:

```
maxSseq_hlp :: Int -> Int -> [Sseq] -> Int
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax [] = max curmax prevmax
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax ((S x):xs) = maxSseq_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax (x:xs)
maxSseq_hlp curmax prevmax (E:xs) = maxSseq_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) xs
```

and this is what I would advise if you need to find the *max. length element*:

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

len :: Sseq -> Int
len E = 0
len (S x) = 1 + len x

maxSseq :: [Sseq] -> Sseq
maxSseq = maximumBy (comparing len)
```